# for loops and enum

Tags: java, for-loop, enums

There are 12 months in a year.

I need to define an enumeration (enum) of each of the month. I also need to utilize a for loop to display each month.

The part im stuck on is that we need to format our output to look like this:

Month 1: JAN

Month 2: FEB

...

Month 12: DEC

So far, this is my code:

```
enum Month {JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC}
for (Month m : m.values())
{
   System.out.println(m);
}
```

Would I need to do a nested for-loop in order to have "Month (# of Month) : " show?

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Month" + i + ": ");
    for (Month m : m.values())
    { 
       System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Sorry if this may not compile (i'm not on my computer with my IDE)
But I know if i do that nested loop, its going to list ALL the values of the enum for each iteration of the outside loop. I tried to replace the inside statement to say "System.out.println(m.value(i));" but that doesn't work because the compiler states that the method doesnt work on int types. So what can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Given your `Month` enum you can access `ordinal()` and `name()` to get your output. Something like,

```
for (Month m : Month.values()) {
    System.out.printf("Month %d: %s%n", m.ordinal() + 1, m.name());
}
```

Comment: And Java 8 has a built-in `java.time.Month` enum, so you might even skip that, except of course if you have to create your own as part of the exercise.